# Create transparent css border with triangle

Tags: html, image, css, border

I'm trying the find a way to have a dynamic border with a triangle. For the moment, with the basic gradient effect, this is what I did:

[My current effect in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTwBc.png)

But as you can see, the background has a gradient and we can see the border background that does not match..

How can I achieve this effect? Also, the text may vary on different screen size and with other words.

Thank you!

Comment: http://codepen.io/miroot/pen/qwIgC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `pseudo-elements` and `skewX` is one clean way to achieve this. Check this out, I'm using a top, left & right border on the element, and then style the `before` as the left bottom border and the `after` as the right one:

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #999 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, black 75%, black), linear-gradient(45deg, black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, #999 75%, #999);
  background-size: 10px 10px;
  background-position: 0 0, 50px 50px;
}

.dialog {
  text-align: center;
  color: green;
  font-size: 65px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-width: 5px 5px 0 5px;
  border-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.dialog:before {
  content: '';
  border-top: 5px solid red;
  border-right: 5px solid red;
  transform-origin: left top;
  transform: skewX(45deg);
  position: absolute;
  content: ' ';
  height: 10px;
  width: 46%;
  background: inherit;
  left: -5px;
  bottom: -10px;
}
.dialog:after {
  content: '';
  border-top: 5px solid red;
  border-left: 5px solid red;
  transform-origin: left top;
  transform: skewX(-45deg);
  position: absolute;
  content: ' ';
  height: 10px;
  width: 46%;
  background: inherit;
  right: -5px;
  bottom: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dialog">Here I am</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can make it with a background image, for exemple http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/carousel-reviews-with-rating.

As you can see he take an image and resize it to take only a triangle like this:

```
.sprite-i-triangle {
background-position: 0 -1298px;
height: 44px;
width: 50px;
}
```

Try to find an image that meets your expectations. Otherwise you have some exemples in this site. (http://bootsnipp.com)